# How to change the block color without theme?

Tags: beamer, block, examples

How to change the block color without theme?
I want to change `examplebox` and `alert` color.

- title style:

  - fg: white
  - bg: example block title color
- body style:

  - fg: black
  - bg: example block title color!10

I wrote following code, but I couldn't be realized.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,255}]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=block title example, fg=white,bg=block title example.fg}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.fg!10}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{block}
        This is block.
    \end{block}
    \begin{exampleblock}{exampleblock}
        This is exampleblock.
    \end{exampleblock}
    \begin{alertblock}{alertblock}
        This is alertblock.
    \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- after insert `\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!} \setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=block title example, fg=white,bg=block title example.fg}`
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=block title example, fg=white,bg=block title example.fg}` you define the colour based on itself, this will result in a loop.

Instead, you can change the colours like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,255}]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!}

\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{use=alerted text,fg=white,bg=alerted text.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=example text,fg=white,bg=example text.fg!75!black}

\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{parent=normal text,use=block title alerted,bg=block title alerted.bg!10!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.bg!10!bg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{block}
        This is block.
    \end{block}
    \begin{exampleblock}{exampleblock}
        This is exampleblock.
    \end{exampleblock}
    \begin{alertblock}{alertblock}
        This is alertblock.
    \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know you said you'd like to change the colours without theme, but what you describe is exactly what the `orchid` colour theme does. It changes the colours of the blocks, nothing more or less:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,255}]{structure}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{block}
        This is block.
    \end{block}
    \begin{exampleblock}{exampleblock}
        This is exampleblock.
    \end{exampleblock}
    \begin{alertblock}{alertblock}
        This is alertblock.
    \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```